# On Duplicate Key Update - million times per day optimization?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I am using the following query with different variables millions of times per day, and I am wondering if there is any way to optimize it:

```
    INSERT INTO campaign_stats (user_id, date, $country) 
    VALUES      (:user_id, :date, :country) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $country=$country+1
```

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $country=$country+1` is true in 99% of the time, so it might be better to check for it first?

Answer (score 1):

The table *is* InnoDB, correct?  (If not, that change would be important.)

If there is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, you will burning most of a million values each day.  Please provide`SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

That's about 12/second -- not a deadly rate of changes.

Please time the IODKU and time the following, then report back:

```
UPDATE ... country=country+1;
if rows_affected = 0 then
INSERT ...,
```

I suspect they will be about the same speed, but I have not tested it.

Oops, I have a subtle bug in that code -- If another thread sneaks in and does the Insert while I am fumbling around with rows_affected, then the Insert could get "dup key".  The fix:  Change the INSERT to IODKU.

If you end up with more than 100/second, consider collecting the values, then patch applying them.  I would probably do a variant on http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking it (I think you mean running `SELECT` prior to update/insert), you can just issue `UPDATE`, and if number of affected rows is 0, run `INSERT`.
Compared to `SELECT` and then either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` approach you execute 1 statement in the most cases vs 2.

However, both approaches will be much faster compared to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if
- it performs updates most of the time
- you have before insert triggers

Before insert triggers are fired before constraints checked,  then inserts failed due to unique constraint violation, data changes made by triggers will be rolled back (all behind the scene),  finally update successfully completes.